# How to embed a photo at the end of an email?

Tags: vba, outlook, embed

How can I embed a photo at the end of an email?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
        LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .Display
        End With
        signature = OutMail.body

        With OutMail

            .To = cell.Value
            .CC = "xxxxx@gmail.com; xxxxxx@hotmail.com"
            .Subject = "Hello"
            .body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & _
                  vbNewLine & _
                  vbNewLine & _
                    "Body" & _
                   signature

            sourcefile = "XXXXXXX"
            sourcefile1 = "XXXXXX"
            .Attachments.Add sourcefile
            .Attachments.Add sourcefile1

            .Send

        End With
        Set OMail = Nothing
        Set OApp = Nothing

        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code works.

I would like to embed a Xmas image (JPEG). I have done a dig around the internet however am unable to figure it out what command function I can use to embed  it.

Comment: Remark out all the error handling stuff and then see what error you get on what line, and then include that in your question.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905847/embedding-image-in-outlook-with-vba

Comment: Body content disappeared after inserting

.Attachments.Add emails
                .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\VAS PT 04\Desktop\12345678.jpeg", olByValue, 0
                .HTMLBody = "<BODY><IMG src=""cid:12345678..jpeg""> </BODY>"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the HTMLBody property of the email, as plain text wont let you embed an image.

You will also need to know the filename (not only path) of your image. An example of code that might work is:

```
On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
   LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
    .Display
    End With
        signature = OutMail.body


    With OutMail

        .To = cell.Value
        .CC = "xxxxx@gmail.com; xxxxxx@hotmail.com"
        .Subject = "Hello"

        imgpath = "c:\XXXXXX\"
        sourcefile = "XXXXXXX"
        sourcefile1 = "XXXXXX"
        .Attachments.Add imgpath & sourcefile
        .Attachments.Add imgpath & sourcefile1
        .HTMLBody = "<body><p>Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
              & "<br/>& _
                "Body" & _
               signature & _
               "<IMG src=""""cid:""" & sourcefile & """ width=200></body>"

        .Send

End With
Set OMail = Nothing
Set OApp = Nothing


    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi sorry I have never really used html before, the HTMLBody does not seem to working when i subbed my variables in

Comment: You'll need to check that it's valid html. Perhaps put a watch on the .send, and put the .htmlbody contents into a checker (or here?). Example - I have a <p> open tag above, but no </p>close tag

Comment: hi sorry, would you be able to speak simple english, I have got a few paragraphs to chuck in for the body however have no idea what these syntax <body>, <br/>, </p> mean hence have 0 idea where to put in my contents and how to separate them into paragraphs thanks a lot! #newtovba

Comment: For basic HTML see here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/  the email must start with <body> and end with </body> everything in the middle is standard html