# how to correctly format outlook email signatures

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

My first problem is the following, after creating a signature the formatting is lost after sending an email.
And also the images are lost after sending the email:

the signature after sending
[image]

but it should stay that way:

[image]

follows the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
             <!-- BEGIN : CTA / Background image -->
             <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/1zLp6P10/base.png" alt="" border="0" width="600" height="211" style="display:block;" />
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600; height:211; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; border: 0; z-index: 2">
<v:fill color="#ffffff" opacity="0%" style="z-index: 1;" />
<div>

<![endif]-->
<!-- Containing Table START-->
            <table width="600" height="220" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/1zLp6P10/base.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: left bottom;">

                
               <tbody>
                
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td width="200px" height="65" style="margin-bottom:50px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top:10px; ">
                            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9FSsDRNr/logo.png" width="193" height="62" alt=""/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="220px" style="margin-right: 80px;">
                            <p style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: 700; color:#1269b0; font-size: 24px; ">
                                Name<br><span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; color:#1269b0; font-size: 18px;">IT Analyst</span>
                            </p>
                            <p>&nbsp; </p>
                            <p style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; color:#1269b0; font-size: 18px;">
                                55<span style="font-weight: 400;">95555555</span><br>
                                <a href="https://www.informationsys.com/" style="text-decoration: none; color:#000000;"><span style="font-weight: 400;">www.informatiosys</span>.com</a></p></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                   
                    
                </tbody>

            </table>
  
           
           
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
               


            <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding-top:1px;">
                        <td style="margin-left:25px">
                            
                          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/information-systems-international"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jjdsXJtt/lk.png" width="28" height="28" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100066764434982"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/C5JBvpXQ/fc.png" width="28" height="28" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com/information_systems_/"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Hsy149MQ/in.png" width="28" height="28" alt=""/></a><br>
            <span style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 12px;">Av. aaaaaaaaaaaaa, 0000 - 0º andar, sala 00<br>São Paulo - SP CEP 00000-000</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                      <!-- Containing Table END-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</div></v:fill></v:rect><![endif]-->

            <!-- END : CTA / Background image -->
    enter code here
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are inserting images correctly - it's normal in Outlook to have to download images first. That's just an Outlook problem. Inserting images via cid may show up other issues with other email clients, so I wouldn't advise that. (But you also have other issues, I know)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook may block internet-based images automatically. Read more about that in the [Inline images may display as a Red X in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/inline-images-may-display-as-a-red-x-in-outlook-704ae8b5-b9b6-d784-2bdf-ffd96050dfd6) article. Instead, you can attach images and then refer to the attached files using a special syntax using the `cid:` prefix. For example, in VBA you could do the following:

```
.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\JoeSchmo\Pictures\WF_Communications.jpg", olByValue, 0
.HTMLBody = "<BODY><IMG src=""cid:image.jpg"" width=200> </BODY>"
```

See [Embedding image in email with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905847/embedding-image-in-email-with-vba) for more information.