Is it possible to embed an image in a HTML signature?
I have a HTML signature that I want to send from Outlook desktop and I need the images in it to be attached so that I'm not depending on clients to click to download when opening them also in Outlook.
I know there's something called CID images, but I can't find how to create them and I think I'm probably out of my depth there.
I don't know if someone can help me out or point me to some info to get started.
Thanks


<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: Arial; background-color: #fff; color: #161616; line-height: 1; text-align: left; text-justify: inter-word; width: 100%; max-width: 480px;">        

    <tr>
    <td width="80px"></td><td width="80px"></td><td width="80px"></td><td width="80px"></td><td width="80px"></td><td width="80px"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
<td colspan="2" style="border-bottom: solid 8px #FE5000; text-align: left; vertical-align:bottom; padding:0 0 10 10;"><img style="text-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/VyRjows.png" height="70" alt="SIC" /></td>
<td colspan="4" style="border-bottom: solid 8px #FE5000; text-align: right; vertical-align:bottom; padding:0 10 10 0; font-size:1.2em;"><span>Nombre Apellido</span></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="padding:15 0 0 10;">
<span> <img style="text-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/uUnFDgE.png" height="14" alt="Móvil" /><a href="tel:+000000000" target="_blank" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;000&nbsp;000&nbsp;000&nbsp; </a></span>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4" style="padding:15 0 0 0;">
<span><img style="text-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/aSSuQZF.png" height="14" alt="Mail" /><a href="mailto:mail@sicinformatica.es" target="_blank" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;mail@sicinformatica.es&nbsp; </a></span>
    </td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="padding:15 0 0 10;">
<span> <img style="text-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/r8bnG1U.png" height="14" alt="Teléfono" /><a href="tel:+000000000" target="_blank" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;000&nbsp;000&nbsp;000&nbsp; </a></span>
        </td>
    <td colspan="4" style="padding:15 0 0 0;">
<span><img style="text-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/j1JnEZi.png" height="14" alt="Web" /><a href="http://www.sicinformatica.net" target="_blank" style="color: #000; text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;www.sicinformatica.net&nbsp; </a></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="padding:15 0 0 10;">
<span> <img style="text-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/2AHl58A.png" height="14" alt="Fax" />&nbsp;000&nbsp;000&nbsp;000 </span>
        </td>
    <td colspan="4" style="padding:15 0 0 0;">
<span>C/Dirección, 15009, A Coruña</span>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; padding:15 10 15 10;">
<img style="text-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/IfGGjuD.png" height="30" alt="Farmatic" />
        </td>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; padding:15 10 15 10;">
<img style="text-align:center;" src="https://i.imgur.com/LzWI7MP.png" height="30" alt="Glint" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>  
         
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family: Arial; background-color: #fff; color: #161616; line-height: 1; text-align: left; text-justify: inter-word; width: 100%;">
    <tr cellpadding="0" style="text-align:justify; line-height:1; font-size:0.7em; color: #999;">
    <td colspan="6" style="border-top: solid 8px #BBBCBC; padding:0;">
<br><b>AVISO LEGAL:</b> Este mensaje y sus archivos adjuntos van dirigidos exclusivamente a su destinatario, pudiendo contener información confidencial sometida a secreto profesional. No está permitida su comunicación, reproducción o distribución sin la autorización expresa de SIC, Servicios Informáticos Coruña, S.L.. Si usted no es el destinatario final, por favor elimínelo e infórmenos por esta vía.

<br><b>PROTECCIÓN DE DATOS:</b> De conformidad con lo dispuesto en el Reglamento (UE) 2016/679 de 27 de abril de 2016 (GDPR), y la Ley Orgánica 3/2018, de 5 de diciembre (LOPDGDD), le informamos que los datos personales y dirección de correo electrónico, recabados del propio interesado o de fuentes públicas, serán tratados bajo la responsabilidad de SIC, Servicios Informáticos Coruña, S.L. para el envío de comunicaciones sobre nuestros productos y servicios y se conservarán mientras exista un interés mutuo para ello. Los datos no serán comunicados a terceros, salvo obligación legal. Le informamos que puede ejercer los derechos de acceso, rectificación, portabilidad y supresión de sus datos y los de limitación y oposición a su tratamiento dirigiéndose a C/ Antonio Ríos, 70 15009 A Coruña (A CORUÑA). Email: <a href="mailto:sicsl@sicinformatica.es" target="_blank" style="color: #FE5000;">sicsl@sicinformatica.es</a>. Si considera que el tratamiento no se ajusta a la normativa vigente, podrá presentar una reclamación ante la autoridad de control en <a href="https://www.aepd.es" target="_blank" style="color: #FE5000;">www.aepd.es</a>.

 <br><b>PUBLICIDAD:</b> En cumplimiento de lo previsto en el artículo 21 de la Ley 34/2002 de Servicios de la Sociedad de la Información y Comercio Electrónico (LSSICE), si usted no desea recibir más información sobre nuestros productos y/o servicios, puede darse de baja enviando un correo electrónico a <a href="mailto:sicsl@sicinformatica.es" target="_blank" style="color: #FE5000;">sicsl@sicinformatica.es</a>, indicando en el Asunto «BAJA» o «NO ENVIAR».
        </td>
    </tr> 

    </table>
</body>




Can you show the HTML you already have?

You can create a new signature with an image in Outlook and see how it handles images. The signature along with its files will be in c:\Users<suer name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\

see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38906686/4539709

@Jerico I just did

@Om3r I just don't understand where do I run the code shown there, I'm not using any third party software to send the emails, I just use Outlook
